# How is an L77 pool/snooker table bumper mounted to the rail?

Tags: pool, snooker

An L77 pool/snooker table bumper has an L shape:
[image: L77 pool table bumper]

How is is placed on the pool table rail? with the long side parallel to the top of the rail, or at an angle?

In the beautiful picture below, rather A or B?

[image: L77 bumper placement question]

I can find plenty of section diagrams of rails with K66 bumpers, but none for L77.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither, it is mounted just like it is shown in the diagram. The 0.75" side is mounted to a flat rail and the long side is extends in line with the top of the rail. Like so:
[image: L77 Bumper]

You can see an example of this in the following video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEmCmWUNxnw